# reference amsthm theorem with item list inside

Tags: hyperref, links, amsthm

Here is my minimum example. Click from right to left 2-1-1 and notice that it jumps correctly to item 2 then item 1. But then it doesn't jump to remark 1, but instead to the entire first page, as it does when an invalid link is specified. Why is this? It must have to do with `amsthm`, because when I remove that, it works. But I don't want to remove it since in the real file its predefined styles are used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}
\newtheorem{_Remark}{Remark}
\begin{document}
\begin{_Remark}
\label{rmk:1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{rmk:1a}this is a.
\item \label{rmk:1b}this is b.
\end{enumerate}
\end{_Remark}
\ref{rmk:1}-\ref{rmk:1a}-\ref{rmk:1b}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I only got the order wrong. Once I include `amsthm` after `hyperref` all is fine. I thought I once read somewhere always to include `hyperref` last. Guess that's just not true any more.